# What's "it" for?

Tags: elisp, dash.el

For example in the definition of `-first` we have:

```
(--first (funcall pred it) list))
```

Naturally the meaning of "it" is very hard to google or search in the manual.

Comment: Precisely the question one should ask, and a reasonable general criticism of anaphoric this-and-that. In **Emacs**, at least (it is "the self-documenting editor"), ***each doc string*** of an anaphoric thingie should clearly call it out, even if that seems verbose to some who are familiar with it (sic), and even if it is well documented in a manual. (Just one opinion.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually it's right there in the manual: https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#anaphoric-functions.

### Update: inspecting and flattening macros

If you're using [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy), starting with:

```
;; anaphoric version
(--map (* it it) '(1 2 3 4))
```

and the point before `(--map`, you can press <kbd>xf</kbd> to call `lispy-flatten` and obtain:

```
;; anaphoric version
(mapcar (lambda (it) (* it it)) (quote (1 2 3 4)))
```

It's a bit more complex with this code, since dash is too eager to delegate and postpone:

```
(--reduce (max it acc) '(1 2 3 4))
```

After <kbd>xfM</kbd>:

```
(let ((list-value (quote (1 2 3 4))))
  (if list-value (--reduce-from (max it acc)
                                (car list-value)
                                (cdr list-value))
    (let (acc it)
      (max it acc))))
```

After <kbd>fjfxfM</kbd>:

```
(let ((list-value (quote (1 2 3 4))))
  (if list-value (let ((acc (car list-value)))
                   (--each (cdr list-value)
                     (setq acc (max it acc)))
                   acc)
    (let (acc it)
      (max it acc))))
```

After <kbd>fjxfM</kbd>:

```
(let ((list-value (quote (1 2 3 4))))
  (if list-value (let ((acc (car list-value)))
                   (let ((list (cdr list-value))
                         (it-index 0))
                     (while list (let ((it (car list)))
                                   (setq acc (max it acc)))
                            (setq it-index (1+ it-index))
                            (!cdr list)))
                   acc)
    (let (acc it)
      (max it acc))))
```

Suffice to say, that `it` is the implicit iterable var and `acc` is
the implicit accumulator var.

At one point, I tried to add a short lambda patch to Emacs that would enable this notation,
which I think is simpler than anaphoric macros:

```
(map #(* % %) '(1 2 3 4))
(cl-reduce #(max %1 %2) '(1 2 3 4))
```

However, it kind of went nowhere.

Comment: For those without lispy, pp-macroexpand-last-sexp should also do the trick.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that function. It's using a different approach for multilining than me.